# Table goes beyond column width and collides with text in the next column. How do I force it to compress its width?

Tags: tables, columns, width

I’m writing a document in LaTex with 2 columns where I want a table to ideally be of the same width as the column. I’m not that LaTex savvy so I used an online editor to create the code for my table, and it almost looks the way I want it. Here is the code:

```
\begin{table}[]
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\hline
Pre-processing & NV$^a$(LV$^b$) & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Calibration} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Validation} \\ \cline{3-6} 
                 &          & RMSE            & R$^2$         & RMSE      & R$^2$               \\ \hline
$R(\lambda)$                      & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$D^1(R(\lambda))$                 & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$D^2(R(\lambda))$                 & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$-log(R(\lambda))$                & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$-log(D^1(R(\lambda))$            & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$-log(D^2(R(\lambda))$            & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$D^1(-log(R(\lambda)))$           & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$D^2(-log(R(\lambda)))$           & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$MSC(R(\lambda))$                 & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$MSC(D^1(R(\lambda)))$            & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$MSC(D^2(R(\lambda)))$            & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$MSC(-log(R(\lambda)))$           & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$MSC(D^1(-log(R(\lambda))))$      & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$MSC(-log(D^1(R(\lambda))))$      & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$MSC(D^2(-log(R(\lambda))))$      & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$MSC(-log(D^2(R(\lambda))))$      & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$SNV(R(\lambda))$                 & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$SNV(D^1(R(\lambda)))$            & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$SNV(D^2(R(\lambda)))$            & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$SNV(-log(R(\lambda)))$           & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$SNV(D^1(-log(R(\lambda))))$      & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$SNV(-log(D^1(R(\lambda))))$      & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$SNV(D^2(-log(R(\lambda))))$      & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
$SNV(-log(D^2(R(\lambda))))$      & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
Multiple simultaneous             & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\       \hline
\end{tabular}
\textit{$^a$Number of variables active in final variable     selection,$^b$optimal number of latent variables in PLS regression model.}
\end{table}
```

And when I generate the table it looks like in this image here:
[image]

The main problem is that it is too wide. It does not stay within the column width but collides with text in the column to the right. How can I force it to adjust the spaces in the table so it keeps to the column width?

Thanks

Comment: Put `(LV$^b$)` below `NV$^a$`. Abbreviate `RMSE` if it is wider than the cell contents below it. Remove the space to the left and right of the tabular by starting it with `\begin{tabular}{@{}llllll@{}}`. Reduce the inter-column space using `\setlength\tabcolsep{...}`. Choose a smaller font by adding `\small` before the table.

Comment: @Petahanks, do your question is solved by comments or is one of received answers helpful to you? If the former is the case, than I will suggest to close your question as solved by comment. Otherwise, please please respond to answers' authors with comment or even better with voting or acceptation one of those answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following changes:

- use `tabularx` with prescribed width of one column for table environment
- reduce `\tabcolsep` to half (3pt)
- reduce font size to `\small`
- use `multirow` for header of second column
- define new command for shortness of `\multicolumn`
- the first column define as math environment
- use rules from `booktabs` packages
- use `threeparttable` for table notes

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx, threeparttable}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
    \begin{table}[htb]
\begin{threeparttable}[htb]
    \caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
    \small%footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{$}l<{$} >{\centering}X cc cc@{}}
    \toprule
                            & \multirow{2}{=}{\centering 
                                               NV\tnote{a}   \\
                                              (LV\tnote{b})} 
                                   & \mcc{Calibration} & \mcc{Validation} \\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
\text{Pre-processing}       &      & RMSE & R$^2$ & RMSE    & R$^2$\\ 
    \midrule
R(\lambda)                  & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
D^1(R(\lambda))             & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
D^2(R(\lambda))             & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
-log(R(\lambda))            & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
-log(D^1(R(\lambda))        & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
-log(D^2(R(\lambda))        & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
D^1(-log(R(\lambda)))       & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
D^2(-log(R(\lambda)))       & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
MSC(R(\lambda))             & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
MSC(D^1(R(\lambda)))        & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
MSC(D^2(R(\lambda)))        & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
MSC(-log(R(\lambda)))       & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
MSC(D^1(-log(R(\lambda))))  & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
MSC(-log(D^1(R(\lambda))))  & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
MSC(D^2(-log(R(\lambda))))  & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
MSC(-log(D^2(R(\lambda))))  & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
SNV(R(\lambda))             & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
SNV(D^1(R(\lambda)))        & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
SNV(D^2(R(\lambda)))        & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
SNV(-log(R(\lambda)))       & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
SNV(D^1(-log(R(\lambda))))  & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
SNV(-log(D^1(R(\lambda))))  & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
SNV(D^2(-log(R(\lambda))))  & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
SNV(-log(D^2(R(\lambda))))  & X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\
\text{Multiple simultaneous}& X(X) & X    & X     & X       & X    \\       
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]\itshape
\item[a]    Number of variables active in final variable selection,
\item[b]    optimal number of latent variables
        in PLS regression model.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use [adjustbox](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox/adjustbox.pdf) and resize your table to fit the desired width.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[]
        \caption{My caption}
        \label{my-label}
            \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
                \begin{tabular}{llllll}
                    .....
                \end{tabular}
            \end{adjustbox}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```